# $p$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, normed-spaces

How I can show that $$\lim_{p \to \infty} \|x\|_{p} = \max\{|x_1|, \; |x_2|, \; \cdot ,\; |x_n|\}$$ if $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the p-norm? $p > 1$ of course.

Has anyone done this or know how to? I'm reading about p-norms and this was states, but not shown in the text.

Comment: It's a classic limit problem. Factor your norm by the max and show that the limit converges to 1.

Comment: I found it very instructive to look at some simple cases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$. What happens is that the $p$-norm emphasizes the larger coordinate values and ignores the smaller ones. The larger the $p$, the more pronounced the effect. You can even write a little computer program to convince yourself that the larger the $p$, the *only* thing that matters is the largest of the coordinate values. For example $(1^{10} + 5^{10})^{\frac{1}{10}}$ is practically 5. That's the insight, not the formal proof, of course.

Comment: Very neat! Nicely done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\lvert x_k\rvert=\max\{\lvert x_1\rvert,\ldots,\lvert x_n\rvert\}$, then for all $p$
$$
\lvert x_k^p\rvert\le \|x\|_p^p\le n\lvert x_k\rvert^p,
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert x_k\rvert\le \|x\|_p\le n^{1/p}\lvert x_k\rvert.
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{p\to\infty}\|x\|_p=\lvert x_k\rvert=\max\{\lvert x_1\rvert,\ldots,\lvert x_n\rvert\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\|x\|_\infty^p\le \| x \|_p^p \le n\|x\|_\infty^p
$$